# Non Standart UITabBarItem Action

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have UITabBarController with view [image]

So on every TabBar I have ViewController. But on my center UITabBarItem I need to call something like modal UIViewController. And It should be like this
[image]

My UITabBarController class look like

```
class PlanetTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBar.tintColor = kTintColor

        var items = self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem]
        let centredTabBar:UITabBarItem = items[2]
        self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50

        centredTabBar.image = ktabCentredBarImage
        self.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0

        self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        // self.tabBar.backgroundImage = ktabBarImage
        self.tabBar.backgroundImage?.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets

        print( UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName)
        if( UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName != "iPhone 6" && UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName != "iPhone 6 Plus") {
           self.tabBar.backgroundImage = ktabBarImage 
        }
        if( UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPad 2" ) {
            self.tabBar.backgroundImage = ktabBarImage
        }

        if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 10) {
            let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
            let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:font]
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

I really have no idea how to override standart calling of UIViewController and call modal like this =) Please give me advice where I need to search

Comment: What is the question? To create a custom UITabBarItem? Are you simply wanting to present a view if someone touches that center planet image?

Comment: I need to show popupView after tapping on the center UITabBarItem. Do not show ViewController on all screen as standart - just show modal viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can either place a `UIButton` in the same area as the `UITabBarItem` and fire an action or you can simply fire an action when the `selectedSegmentIndex` changes("value changed" in IB) for the `UITabBar` after creating a center `UITabBarItem`. The design choice is yours. The first step is to understand the objects you're working with. It would probably be easier to just add a button, center aligned, over top of the standard UITabBar at the bottom so you don't deal with a custom UITabBarController to handle that non-uniform image above the tab bar.

Or just create your own TabBar down there. It's very simply to setup a few UIButtons or UIViews next to one another that don't have a static height such as a `UITabBarController` which would allow for that center object.

[UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/)

[UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

[Presenting a ViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)